# Mockito anyBoolean() matcher exception on return

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito

Trying to write a simple unit test with Mockito:

```
@Test
    public void toggleBlockingControlTest_turnOff() {
        when(mainViewPresenter.getAppSettingsStorage().loadBlockingStatus())
                .thenReturn(Mockito.anyBoolean());

        AppSettingsStorage appSettingsStorage = mainViewPresenter.getAppSettingsStorage();
        boolean statusBefore = appSettingsStorage.loadBlockingStatus();

        Mockito.verify(appSettingsStorage).saveBlockingStatus(Mockito.eq(!statusBefore));
    }
```

In runtime i got org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: at this string:

```
.thenReturn(Mockito.anyBoolean());
```

I am new to Mockito and can't understand why this framework cant return any boolean???

Comment: If you don't care what value the mocked `loadBlockingStatus()` returns (and that's *not* what `anyBoolean()` is for), there's no point specifying it - the mock would return `false` by default (in your case you'd need to ensure you're setting the `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` flag). Is `mainViewPresenter` even a mock? You should include a bit more of the surrounding code and add the full stack trace. It looks like you're mocking the class you want to test - which essentially defeats the purpose of testing.

Comment: Tnx for reply - i think i have a conceptional missunderstanding of this testing algo. I realy don't care about returning boolean....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
when(mainViewPresenter.getAppSettingsStorage().loadBlockingStatus())
                .thenReturn(Mockito.anyBoolean());
```

Here you should return either `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`. And If you don't care about this boolean value then :

Replace: `Mockito.anyBoolean()  --> Boolean.TRUE /Boolean.FALSE`